# Computer not booting properly

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

I just recently bought new computer parts for my little brother (specs below). So he could play some games. however, the computer doesn't want to boot properly. It does boot, where all the fans spins up, but it doesn't show any screen of some sort. It doesn't give any beeps or anything that could indicate a problem.

I tried:

1. Use the default intergrated graphics, instead of my (working) GTX 660.
2. Use my GTX 660 from my own computer.
3. Remove most "plugs" I could, that means removing the graphic card, optic drive and hard disk.
4. Remove all wires/cords completely and re-plug them, which I did a few times, just to make sure.
5. Used the new RAM stick in my own computer.

The only new parts, were the CPU, RAM & Motherboard.

Specs:
CPU: Intel Celeron G1620.

Motherboard: Zotac H61MAT-A-E (I know, I was on a really tight budget).

RAM: Corsair XMS3 1600MHz 1x4GB (http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0045HXQV4)

Any ideas, to what I could do that could resolve this issue? I really don't want to return the items.

Comment: It can be a few things. Such as ram not fitted properly, or wrong kind of ram. Its also possible the CPU heatsink is not properly installed, and the computer doesn't power up to prevent damage. I've seen it before. Try removing the heatsink, remove all coolingpaste, reapply coolingpaste and secure the whole again.

Comment: It was a stock cooler, so the thermal paste was already applied, but I'll give it a shot regardless. I also tried switching the RAM slots, which didn't work either.

Comment: Also, it is possible that a component (such as the mainboard) is defective. It happens. Its called DoA (Dead on Arrival). If all fails, call the store you ordered the components, and tell them your problem and what you tested. They'll then allow you to do a RMA procedure to send it back and get a new set of components.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, I will RMA it if I cannot get it working by tomorrow. I just want to make sure that I haven't missed anything, before sending it back.

Comment: Yes, of course. :)